# Press the same key to do different actions

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I wanna press the letter "L" to remove something and then press "L" again to add the thing that i removed.
I can do the part that removes with this code:

```
  document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);

    function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
        // Get the key code of the pressed key 
        var keyCode = event.which;
        console.log("l" + keyCode);
        if (keyCode == 76) {
            scene.remove(directionalLight);
        }

        render();
    }
```

I tried doing:

```
    else if (keyCode == 76) {
        scene.add(directionalLight);
    }
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

So how can i press the same key in order to do "scene.add(directionalLight);" ?

Comment: So keep state of the action

Comment: just check if the light is already there, like `scene.getObjectByName()  ? remove : add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```cs
//use a variable to keep track of if the directional light exists
bool light = true;

document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);

    function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
        // Get the key code of the pressed key 
        var keyCode = event.which;
        console.log("l" + keyCode);
        if (keyCode == 76) {
            //check the status of the variable to decide what to do, 
            //and update its status
            if (light) {
                scene.remove(directionalLight);
                light = false;
            } else {
                scene.add(directionalLight);
                light = true;
            }
        }

        render();
    }
```

This is a pretty simple strategy for alternating between two behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

You would need another condition to check if the scene has been added or not. I'm not familiar with three.js, so I don't know if there's a variable you could check like `scene.isAdded` or not, but you can create your own. I created a variable called `isAdded` in the code below:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);

let isAdded = true; // define the variable outside of the function

function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
    // Get the key code of the pressed key 
    var keyCode = event.which;
    console.log("l" + keyCode);
    if (keyCode == 76) {
        if (isAdded) {
            console.log('remove');
            scene.remove(directionalLight);
        } else {
            console.log('add');
            scene.add(directionalLight);
        }
        isAdded = !isAdded ; // toggle the isAdded variable
    }

    render();
}
```